# Quicksort Algorithm in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, codeblocks, quicksort, doubly-linked-list

I want to sort a list by last names with the algorithm of Quicksort but when exchanging the elements it does not work, it leaves them as they were

In this part the values of the chains are exchanged

```
void swap(string* a, string* b){


cout<<"A and B are "<<*a<<" - "<<*b<<endl;

string t = *a;
*a = *b;
cout<<" A is ->"<<*a<<endl;

*b= t;
cout<<"B is ->"<<*b<<endl;

}
```

This is where the partition is made. I have noticed that when * i and * j take values they are exactly the same names and therefore can not be compared later. It seems strange to me that this list works if it is a number but when it is strings this error occurs.

```
User *i = lower;
```

But this did not work at the end because the program crashed, but if you change the value of the string

```
User* partition(User *lower, User *high){

cout<<"Lower ->  "<<lower->lastname<<endl;
cout<<"High ->  "<<high->lastname<<endl;
string  pivot = high->lastname;
User *i = bajo->prev;
 for (User *j = lower; j != high; j = j->next)
{
    if (j->lastname.compare(pivot)< 0)
    {
        i = (i == NULL)? lower : i->next;
        cout<<"Atention J e I valen ->"<<i->lastname<<" - "<<j->lastname<<endl;
        swap(&(i->lastname), &(j->lastname));
    }
}
i = (i == NULL)? lower : i->lastname; // Similar to i++
swap(&(i->lastname), &(alto->lastname));
return i;
}
```

What am I failing? How can I make it really take the desired value.

EDITED:

This is the source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class User
{

public :
    string lastname;
    User *next;
    User *prev;
    User()
    {
        lastname= "";
        next=NULL;
        prev=NULL;

    }
    int empty(User *listt)
    {

        if(listt ==  NULL)
        {

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {

            return 0;
        }

    }


    User *Insert(User *listt, string lastName)
    {

        User *temp = new User();

        if(empty(listt))
        {

            temp->lastname=lastName;
            listt = temp;

        }
        else
        {

            temp->lastname=lastName;
            listt->prev=temp;
            temp->next=listt;
            listt=temp;

        }
        return listt;
    }
    void swap(string* a, string* b)
    {

        string t = *a;
        *a = *b;

        *b= t;

    }
    User* partition(User* lower, User* high)
    {

        cout<<"Lower ->  "<<lower->lastname<<endl;
        cout<<"High ->  "<<high->lastname<<endl;
        string  pivot = high->lastname;
        User *i = lower->prev;
        for (User *j = lower; j != high; j = j->next)
        {
            if (j->lastname.compare(pivot)< 0)
            {
                i = (i == NULL)? lower : i->next;
                swap(&(i->lastname), &(j->lastname));
            }
        }
        i = (i == NULL)? lower : i->next; // Similar to i++
        swap(&(i->lastname), &(high->lastname));
        return i;
    }
    User *Last(User *listt)
    {
        User *temp = listt;

        while(temp && temp ->next)
            temp=temp->next;
        return temp;


    }
    void _quickSort( User* lower, User* high)
    {

        if(high != NULL && lower != high&&lower!= high->next)
        {
            User *p = partition(lower,high);
            _quickSort(lower,p->next); //I change this part
            _quickSort(p->next,high);

        }

    }
    void quickSort(User *listt)
    {
        User *h = Last(listt);

        _quickSort(listt, h);


    }
    User *Display(User *listt)
    {

        if(empty(listt))
        {

            cout<<"List empty"<<endl;

        }
        else
        {

            User *temp = new User();
            temp = listt;
            while(temp!= NULL)
            {

                cout<<"The last name is -> "<<temp->lastname<<endl;
                temp=temp->next;
            }

        }
        return listt;


    }
};

int main()
{

    User *listt = NULL;
    User y;
    bool exit = false;
    int opc;
    string lastName;
    while(!exit)
    {

        cout<<"1.-Insert an element"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.-Sort element-(Quicksort)"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.-Show elements"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.-Exitt"<<endl;
        cin>>opc;
        switch(opc)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Inser your last name"<<endl;
            cin>>lastName;
            listt=y.Insert(listt,lastName);
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Sorting...."<<endl;
            y.quickSort(listt);
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 3:
            cout<<"Display..."<<endl;
            y.Display(listt);
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 4:
            exit = true;
            break;



        }




    }




}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: ok ,Thanks i change my post

Comment: These raw pointers are pretty error prone, and duplicate stuff that is already pretty well done in the standard library. The fact that you get crashes at unexpected places indicates that the error is elsewhere, and it catches up to you later -- something we are all familiar with. Posting a few snippits of non-running code here is unlikely to reveal the real culprit.

Comment: If you changet this value the program crash 

User *i = lower;

Comment: On cursory examination, it looks like your _quickSort function selects a pivot, then does the upper part twice, instead of doing the lower part and the upper part.

Comment: Yes it was my error, sorry . I clean the code and I was wrong in that part. But i have the same problem . I think that  `i` doesn't take a different value than `j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_quickSort(lower,p->next); //I change this part
```

This should be `p->prev`. The correct function:

```
void _quickSort(User* lower, User* high)
{
    if(high != NULL && lower != high&&lower != high->next)
    {
        User *p = partition(lower, high);
        _quickSort(lower, p->prev); //change it back!
        _quickSort(p->next, high);
    }
}
```

Additionally there is resource leak in `Display`. Don't allocate new items in display function:

```
User *Display(User *listt)
{
    if(empty(listt))
    {
        cout<<"List empty"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //User *temp = new User(); <== don't allocate new item here
        User *temp = listt;
        while(temp!= NULL)
        {
            cout<<"The last name is -> "<<temp->lastname<<endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }

    }
    return listt;
}
```

Testing with a 1000 items:

```
class User
{
public:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        string lastname;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        Node()
        {
            prev = next = nullptr;
        }
    };

    Node *head;
    User()
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }

    void Insert(string val)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->lastname = val;
        if (head)
        {
            head->prev = temp;
            temp->next = head;
        }
        head = temp;
    }

    void swap(string &a, string &b)
    {
        string t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }

    Node *Tail()
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        while(temp && temp->next)
            temp = temp->next;
        return temp;
    }

    Node* partition(Node* left, Node* right)
    {
        string pivot = right->lastname;
        Node *i = left->prev;
        for(Node *j = left; j != right; j = j->next)
        {
            if(j->lastname < pivot)
            {
                i = (i == nullptr) ? left : i->next;
                swap(i->lastname, j->lastname);
            }
        }
        i = (i == nullptr) ? left : i->next; // Similar to i++
        swap(i->lastname, right->lastname);
        return i;
    }

    void quickSort(Node* left, Node* right)
    {
        if(!left || !right || left == right || left == right->next) 
            return;
        Node *p = partition(left, right);
        quickSort(left, p->prev);
        quickSort(p->next, right);
    }

    void quickSort()
    {
        quickSort(head, Tail());
    }

    void Display()
    {
        string last;
        for (Node *n = head; n; n = n->next)
        {
            if(n->lastname < last)
            {
                cout << "error ***\n";
                break;
            }
            last = n->lastname;
            cout << n->lastname << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    User list;

    list.Insert("z");
    list.Insert("c");
    list.Insert("a");
    list.Insert("g");

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        string str;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            str.push_back('a' + rand() % 26);
        list.Insert(str);
    }

    list.quickSort();
    list.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works with numbers . for some reason, but not with characters. I trying using `z c a g` and it sorts in this way `c a g z ` . I don't know if this method is right `if (j->lastname.compare(pivot)< 0)`

Comment: See edit, I rewrote the class in simpler form with same sort routine as before, it is sorting correctly with your values. Is your teacher forcing you to sort linked-list with quicksort or is this your own idea?

Comment: Wow, you solve it . Thanks, I already saw where my mistakes were. I wanted to check if you could do a quicksort with strings , you know on the internet there are only examples with numbers.

Comment: Note that in a practical C++ application `std::vector` is strongly recommended over linked list (or `std::list`). linked-list or `std::list` had a slight performance advantage in the early days of computers, but that has change in the last 20 years due to modern CPU design, problems with latency, etc. It may not seem obvious but `std::vector` is faster in almost every practical application (and also easier to use). You can also use `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your swap function seems working but `string t = *a;` usage is kind of weird because `*a` is considered as an int value so you should not assign it to a string although the compiler can handle it either way. On the other hand I guess what you mentioned is to copy the value of "a" into a temporary string and it should be done as `string* t = a;`  and then you can do `b = t;`  but instead of that passing by reference is a better practice such as

```
void swap(string &a, string &b){
    string t = a;
    a = b;
    b= t;
}
```

and you may want to check your Quick-sort implementation, see the reference on [this page](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort)

Comment: It sounds great but it doesn't work in my implementation

Comment: you should send references like   swap((i->lastname), (high->lastname));